# How to iterate through a list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, abstract-data-type

Let "List" be a struct that represents a singly-linked list, i have the following function:

```
int List_contains(List node, const char* key) {
    List *search;
    search=node.next; 
    assert(search->key!=NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

and List is  the following struct:

```
typedef struct List { /*A new node*/
    char* key;
    void* value;
    struct List *next;
} List;
```

The function "List_contains" should tell me if "key" is contained in the list or not. Problem is, i can't iterate through the list, and the line

```
assert(search->key != NULL);
```

throws a Segfault. How can i iterate through the list with what i have?

(Note: The function is, obviously, not "completed".)

Comment: did you mean `assert(node != NULL)`? you can't access a null pointers `key` field.

Comment: Why does it segfault? What's the value of  node? (use the debugger)

Comment: To iterate through the list, you need to iterate. This would usually show up as a loop, which you haven't written. To dereference a pointer (such as `node.next`) you _first_ need to check it isn't NULL, which you haven't done

Comment: And yes, if your program segfaults, you already have access to an exact and perfect snapshot of your program state at the moment of failure, which you should learn to investigate in your debugger.

Comment: I agree on what @SamerTufailsaid. If you want to use C++ Iterator on C arrays, you can use the gsl::span to have a small wrapper around the array and use all nice C++ iterator features (e.g. all stl algorithms).

Comment: In my main function i called a function that appends a new node in the list so, when i try to iterate through the list, in the "contains" function, it throws a segfault when i try to access node's key to see if it's equal to the key parameter.

Comment: As `node` is of struct type and not pointer type, how can you compile something like `assert(node->key)` at all?

Comment: My bad, i typed it wrong. I meant to say "search->key"

Comment: When you get to the end of the list, `node.next == NULL`, so `search == NULL` and `search->key` segfaults.  This should not be surprising.

Comment: Do you mean you typed it wrong in the code, or in this question? Which is one reason we ask for the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: This is the reason why you should never ever retype any code from memory but use copy&paste. Hunting for errors in phantasy code doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a search I wrote a while back.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


int
search_list(struct node *head, int search)
{
    if (!head)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid head\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct node *temp = head;

    while (temp)
    {
        if (temp->data == search)
        {
            printf("Found %d\n", search);
            break;
        }

        temp = temp->next;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Returns `0` whether found or not found.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes this was just a example. Return value only signaled if function executed properly. You can modify return values based on need.

Answer (score 0):

```
int List_contains(List node, const char* key) {
    List *search;
    search=node.next; 
    assert(search->key!=NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

so a lot to parse here...

Generally you would pass in a pointer to the `node` so that it isn't copied, but it is actually safe to do what you have done, in this instance, assuming no multithreaded shenanigans go on...

but in the future I would look for:
`int List_contains(List* node, const char* key) {`

next line you make a pointer without a value... which is fine, because you assign it the next line, but that could be condensed...

```
// List *search; 
// search=node.next; # could easily become:
List *search = node.next;
```

now at this point you actually know if you are at the end of the list...

```
if(search == null)
{
     return 0;
}
```

after that you need to do some sort of compare...

```
if (strcmp(key,search->key) == 0)
{
    //found it;
    return 1;
}
```

now you have code that will match the key against the first element of the list, so you would need to put the whole thing in a loop, each iteration swapping `search` with `search->next` and checking for null

Comment: Problem is, my teacher doesn't let me change the interface of the functions. Turns out my problem lies in the "append" function, which doesn't actually append a new node in the list. Not sure why, I'll look into it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sovengarde well, you technically dont need to change that prototype... because the pointers and all of the other members will be copied by value... which works fine in this instance.